# Dynamic form with different data in each form Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a dynamic form on a same component on each time the user click addProcess event button the new input field is generated this dynamic form is using on different Nodes when i submit one Node data when i tried to edit the Different Node the same data reappears i have been working quite a while on this task i have google and tried somethings but they are not worked good as i expected

here is the code of mine render mapping

```
<form>
  {console.log(this.state.nodetext)}

  {this.state.texts.map((text, index) => (
    <div className="shareholder" key={index}>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, index)}
        defaultValue={this.statetext}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => this.handleRemove(index)}
        className="small"
      >
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  ))}
  <button type="button" onClick={e => this.addProcess(e)} className="small">
    Add Process
  </button>

  <button type="button" onClick={e => this.saveProcess(e)} className="small">
    Edit
  </button>
</form>
```

This is my saveProcess State

```
saveProcess = () => {
  let node = this.state.edit;

  let nodes = [...this.state.nodes];

  let index = nodes.findIndex(el => el.id === node.id);
  console.log(this.state.texts);
  nodes[index].text = this.state.texts;
  this.setState({ nodes: nodes, dialogVisible_two: false });
}
```

this is my editProcess Button

```
editProcess = (info, node) => {
  this.setState({
    dialogVisible_two: true,
    info: info.component,
    nodeid: node.id,
    edit: node,
    nodetext: node.text
  });
}
```

This is the result which i have obtained with the nodes
https://gyazo.com/7ac2ad586395143aadf6ab7e913a91b9

but when i click the 2nd Node which have Process written in text field the 1st Node Text appears in that Node form

this is my result when i clicked 2nd Node got Node 1 text

Comment: Have you tried using an other unique value besides index for the key property in your `this.state.texts.map((text, index)` function?

Comment: Yup i have tried this it is looping all the value of text in every Node